# How to set Alarm One Day before to Reminder Date and Two Hours before to Reminder Time on Same Date

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, alarm

I'm trying to set my reminder exactly after two days for current date. For this reminder I want to set alarm before one day for reminder and one more time it should ring in same day two hours before.

```
    public void forday() {
    SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
    int day = parseInt(dayFormat.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
    SimpleDateFormat monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
    int month = parseInt(monthFormat .format(myCalendar.getTime()));

    Calendar before1Day = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar oneDayBefore = Calendar.getInstance();
    Log.d("before1Day", "forday: "+before1Day);
    Log.d("oneDayBefore", "forday: "+oneDayBefore);

    oneDayBefore.set(Calendar.HOUR, hours);
    oneDayBefore.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
    oneDayBefore.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    oneDayBefore.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    oneDayBefore.set(Calendar.DATE, day-1);
    oneDayBefore.set(Calendar.MONTH, (month-1));
    oneDayBefore.set(Calendar.AM_PM,before1Day.get(Calendar.AM_PM));
    Log.d("afteroneDayBefore", "forday: "+oneDayBefore);


    Calendar before2Hours = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar twoHoursBefore = Calendar.getInstance();
    Log.d("before2Hours", "forday: "+before2Hours);
    Log.d("twoHoursBefore", "forday: "+twoHoursBefore);
    twoHoursBefore.set(Calendar.HOUR, hours-2);
    twoHoursBefore.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
    twoHoursBefore.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    twoHoursBefore.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    twoHoursBefore.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
    twoHoursBefore.set(Calendar.MONTH, (month-1));
    twoHoursBefore.set(Calendar.AM_PM,before2Hours.get(Calendar.AM_PM));
    Log.d("AftersettwoHoursBefore", "forday: "+twoHoursBefore);



    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,oneDayBefore.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,twoHoursBefore.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);


    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set  "+oneDayBefore.getTime()+" in seconds",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set  "+twoHoursBefore.getTime()+" in seconds",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("finaloneDayBefore", "forday: "+oneDayBefore.getTime());
    Log.d("finaltwoHoursBefore", "forday: "+twoHoursBefore.getTime());

}
```

Up to before calling intent what I am trying is coming perfect, but after calling intent on words my alarm date is going to change that is one is coming same day and another one is coming after reminder date.(for example I am trying to set reminder at Nov 30th 2017  14.30 before calling intent one alarm is set Nov 29th 2017 14.30 and one more is Nov 30th 2017 12.30, But after calling intent the alarm changing THE  date like first one is Thu Nov 30 02:30:00 GMT+05:30 2017 and second one is Fri Dec 01 00:30:00 GMT+05:30 2017.

Where I am doing mistake?

Comment: Put Multiple Alarms.

Comment: Please tell me why oneDayBefore, twoHoursBefore values are going to change automatically after call intent.

Comment: For Programatically Do This You Have to create Your own Service